# How do I update an object on click without destroying the previous state?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to edit this initial state:

```
const initialFilters = {
    PGfenced: '',
    PGgrill: '',
    PGrestrooms: '',
    PGstaffed: '',
    PGtoddler: '',
    Animals: '',
  };
```

I have this so far and it just adds another object onto the end. I want to edit and replace just part of the `initialFilters`.

```
  const [playgroundFilters, setPlaygroundFilters] = useState([initialFilters]);

  const updateItem = (whichvalue, newvalue) => {
    setPlaygroundFilters({ ...playgroundFilters, [whichvalue]: newvalue });
    console.log(playgroundFilters);
  };
```

```
onPress={(value) => updateItem('PGfenced', value)}
options={[
    { label: 'No Fence', value: '' },
    { label: 'Partially', value: 'Partially fenced' },
    { label: 'Fully', value: 'Fully fenced' },
]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your state variable is an array, but then you assign an object to it. I assume you want it to be an object since you're updating it with a new value, just remove the square brackets in the state declaration like this:

```js
const [playgroundFilters, setPlaygroundFilters] = useState(initialFilters);
```

And then you will be able to update that object the way you did.

Comment: this works but it seems to be one value behind the switch it is on. With each click it logs the current state and then takes another click before it logs correctly.